# Do any familiar adjunctions arise from this construction?

Tags: category-theory, order-theory, galois-connections

I was pondering an answer that user Andreas Blass provided to an [old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276531/basic-question-on-the-ideal-variety-correspondence-and-adjoint-functors) of mine and wondered if the following construction cropped up anywhere other than the example I will provide.

For any set $X$, let $\mathscr P(X)$ be the category whose objects are the subsets of $X$ and whose morphisms are the inclusion maps.  Let $R\subseteq A\times B$ be a binary relation on two sets $A$ and $B$. Then there are two functors
\begin{align*}
F &: \mathscr P(B)\to\mathscr P(A)^{\operatorname{op}} \\
G &: \mathscr P(A)^{\operatorname{op}}\to\mathscr P(B) 
\end{align*}
defined on objects by
\begin{align*}
F(X) &= \{a\in A:x\in X\Rightarrow (a,x)\in R\} \\
G(X) &= \{b\in B:x\in X\Rightarrow (x,b)\in R\}
\end{align*}
One need not work very hard to show that $F$ is left-adjoint to $G$.

A nice example of this occurs in the $\DeclareMathOperator{Spec}{Spec}\Spec$ construction. Let $A$ be a commutative ring and let $R\subseteq A\times \Spec A$ be
$$
R=\{(a,\mathfrak p)\in A\times\Spec A: a\in\mathfrak p\}
$$
The above construction provides us with the familiar functors
\begin{align*}
\Bbb V &:\mathscr P(A)^{\operatorname{op}}\to\mathscr P(\Spec A) \\
\Bbb I &:\mathscr P(\Spec A)\to\mathscr P(A)^{\operatorname{op}}
\end{align*}
defined on objects by
\begin{align*}
\Bbb V(X) &= \{\mathfrak p\in\Spec A:a\in X\Rightarrow (a,\mathfrak p)\in R\} \\
&= \{\mathfrak p\in\Spec A:X\subseteq \mathfrak p\} \\
\Bbb I(X) &=\{a\in A:\mathfrak p\in X\Rightarrow (a,\mathfrak p)\in R\} \\
&= \bigcap_{\mathfrak p\in X}\mathfrak p 
\end{align*}
The abstract-nonsense above tells us that $\Bbb I\dashv \Bbb V$. Since products and coproducts in categories of the form $\mathscr P(X)$ are intersections and unions respectively, the continuity properties of adjoint-pairs give us the familiar formula
$$
\Bbb V\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\right)=\bigcap_{i\in I}\Bbb V(X_i)
$$
Now, I'm not claiming there's anything new or deep going on here but I am curious if this crops up anywhere else. Are there other adjunctions that arise from this construction?

Comment: Galois connection.

Comment: Your example, Galois theory, and the syntax-semantics adjunction are the three big examples I know of.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection

Comment: Thanks for the link @MartinBrandenburg. If the point wasn't made clear by Berci's and Qiaochu's comments or the exact same link provided by the only answer below, it is definitely clear now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is a nice observation.

The adjunction between syntax and semantics is another example. In particular: Let $A$ denote a first-order language and $B$ denote the class of models for that language below some inaccessible $\kappa$. Let $R \subseteq A \times B$ denote the set of all pairs $(s,m)$ such that $s$ is a sentence satisfied by $m$. Then the functions $G$ and $F$ in your question satisfy: $G(S)$ is the set of all models satisfying every sentence in $S$, and $F(M)$ is the set of all sentences satisfied by every model in $M$. Also $F(G(S))$ is the closure of $S$ with respect to the sentences that semantically follow from $S$.

*Remark.* Note that this isn't *really* category theory, rather its the special case called *order theory.* Order theorists tend to call these things "Galois connections" rather than adjunctions, which explains why it was hard to find information elsewhere; your construction is described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection#Examples) at the Galois connection page at wikipedia.